# Problem installing Cabal-1.8.0.2

Tags: 10.10, haskell

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, ghc 6.12.1, gcc 4.4.5.

I am trying to install [Nikki And The Robots](http://joyridelabs.de/).

When I do `cabal install` it fails to install Cabal-1.8.0.2.
Cabal-1.8.0.2 already exists in `~/.cabal/lib`.  If I run cabal install `--dry-run -v`, it will say:

```
In order, the following would be installed:
Cabal-1.8.0.2 (reinstall) changes: unix-2.4.0.0 -> 2.4.2.0
cabal-macosx-0.1.1 (new package)
nikki-0.2.20 (new package)
```

Cabal fail to install with:

```
/home/tyr/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.2.0/ghc-6.12.1/libHSunix-2.4.2.0.a(Signals.o): In function `spzw_info':
(.text+0x4d14): undefined reference to `rtsTimerSignal'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.8.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How do I fix this?

I have tried renaming the .cabal folder to force it to reinstall, but it still fails.

Comment: Migrated to Ask Ubuntu?  Really?  There are more correctly answered problems of this type on Stackoverflow, it even has the 'cabal-install' tag.  The fact that this happened on a linux box is rather incidental?

Comment: Linker error, caused by a buggy compiler with a strong community on StackOverflow?  Ask Ubuntu!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a broken compiler setup.  The symbol you referred to should be in `libHSrts_thr.a` (or a variant, such as the non-threaded).  I suggest you download and use a new copy of GHC, might as well be 7.0.3 while you're at it.

If you really want to investigate more then grep for `rtsTimerSignal` in the `objdump -t libHSrts*.a` output.  Also, you could try to use the threaded rts (`ghc -threaded`) or non-threaded depending on which one is failing here.

Comment: I already have a version istalled form source sitting in a folder, as I was poking around in it, so I'm just going to run make install on it and try again.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, now Network/Socket.hsc is failing with an Ambiguous Reference to closeFDWidth.  *sigh* and thhis is why you list the functions you are importing.

Comment: What!  They do, and it's protected by two mutually exclusive ##if on MIN_VERSION_base(4,3,1) s.  This is odd